# Iterating over a multidimensional bool array?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I am making a game that consists of players trying to capture space stations in a Risk (board game) type format. In order to tell who owns what station I have set up a multidimensional `bool` array like so.

```
bool[,] stationOwners = 
    new bool[3, 5] 
    { 
        //S0    S1     S2     S3     S4 
        {true,  false, false, false, false}, //blue player
        {false, false, true,  false, false}, //red player
        {false, false, false, true,  false}  //green player
    };
```

The rows represent a player while a column represents a specific station on the map. Now the issue I am running into is trying calculate each players income, each station has its own set income value `int[] stationIncome = new int[5] {3,2,3,3,2};`

Also players have their own variable to store their income `int[] playerMoney = new int[3] {0,0,0};`

How I am looking for what player owns which stations is  through a for loop inside a method

```
public void playerTurnStart(int ID)
{
    for(int x = 0; x > 4; x++)
    {
        if (stationOwners[ID, x] == true)
        {
            playerMoney[ID] += stationIncome[x];
        }
    }
    lblPlayerMoney.Text = playerMoney[ID].ToString(); 
}
```

The integer `ID` is tied to what players turn it is. I then make a label on my form equal to the income. The problem is that the players income remains at zero no matter who's turn it is. Is there anyone who could look over this code and see if I missed anything?

Comment: You should post this on code review.  SO is not the right place.

Comment: Could you explain a little better? I am fairly new.

Comment: I think I was pretty clear.  Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and check out [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why not make a class for a player and a class for a station? The station has an income value and the player can have a collection of stations. Then you just iterate each players station collection to get the income.

Comment: If your code works as is, but your looking for pointers on improving performance, readability, etc. then your question would be a better fit for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). However, if there is some problem with the code (errors, unexpected results, etc.) it really belongs here. @roryap, from the statement "*The problem is that the players income remains at zero no matter who's turn it is*" it sounds like this was posted on the correct site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious thing is your `for` loop is incorrect.

`for(int x = 0; x > 4; x++)`

needs to be

`for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)`

Starting at `x = 0` means the condition `x > 4` will never be true.

Comment: Thank you I feel kinda dumb for not seeing that. That was it. Thank you very much.